# Amazon itemLookup not returning new and used count

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm hitting the Amazon Product API with this function:

```
public function itemLookup($id, $responseGroup = 'OfferFull,Images,BrowseNodes,ItemAttributes,Offers'){

    $parameters = array(
    "IdType" => "ASIN",
    "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
    "ItemId" => $id,
    "ResponseGroup" => $responseGroup,
    "Condition" => "Used"
    );

    $signedUrl = $this->getSignedUrl($parameters);

    //return XML to front end
    return $productId = simplexml_load_file($signedUrl);
 }
```

It works and returns the XML document.

However, it doesn't return anything in the:

```
<OfferSummary>
    <TotalNew>0</TotalNew>
    <TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
    <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
    <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
</OfferSummary>
<Offers>
    <TotalOffers>0</TotalOffers>
    <TotalOfferPages>0</TotalOfferPages>
    <MoreOffersUrl>0</MoreOffersUrl>
</Offers>
```

In this particular example, I can visit the product URL and see there are new and used products available.

It seems the API chokes when the item has multiple colors/sizes/options.

Anyone have any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the ItemId that you have passed in? This may be related to Variations (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Variations.html)

"Each color and size combination is called a variation. Each variation, such as a medium, blue shirt, is an item that a customer can buy. For that reason, each variation has its own ASIN. For example, if a shirt came in four sizes and six colors, there would be twenty-four variations and twenty-four corresponding ASINs."